# Nuxt3: Exclude files in /pages

Tags: vue.js, nuxt3, auto-import

how can I exclude some files in `/pages`?
I want to write page-level components just next to the page `[page-name].vue` like
`/[page-name]/cpnt/onlyInThisPage.vue`

I got warning:

```bash
                                                                 4:53:37 PM
[4:53:42 PM]  WARN  Sourcemap for "[paths]/pages/index/context.ts" points to missing source files
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a path, but exclude it, what's the point?

Comment: pages is for router views aka pages. Not a good idea to break the platform convention, especially since file list is read by the framework. Not specific to Nuxt, it's the same in other frameworks